# Quelle différence entre « mot » et « vocable » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, terminologie, linguistique

Quelle différence fait-on entre « mot » et « vocable » ? Quand peut-on préférer « vocable » plutôt que « mot » ?

Wikipédia [suggère](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot) qu'ils sont simplement synonymes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans la langue courante, il se peut que les deux soient interchangeables.

Selon le sens [linguistique](https://books.google.com/books?id=O2224tW6HX4C&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=difference%20entre%20mot%20et%20vocable&source=bl&ots=MBGLxMElHj&sig=vl5oI-WzTddLl3PboCqRj2l8GOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3lbbYgajLAhUIy2MKHa4VCpsQ6AEITjAG#v=onepage&q=difference%20entre%20mot%20et%20vocable&f=false), par contre:

> « La différence entre mot et vocable...est celle-ci: le mot est *virtuel*, il est constitué d'un matériel phonique, tandis que le vocable est l'« *activation* » de ce matériel dans une énonciation faite par un locuteur.  »

Dans la phrase,

> « J'ai un chat noir et un chat blanc. »

Je comprends qu'il y a 9 *mots* et 7 *vocables* (car « **un** » et « **chat** » apparaissent deux fois).

Comment: Merci, je ferai meilleur usage de mes mots maintenant. Mes vocables resteront cependant les mêmes. ;-)

Comment: Dans la langue courante, ils ne sont pas vraiment interchangeables. **Mot** est justement un mot très courant alors que **vocable**, bien que probablement compris par le plus grand nombre, fait essentiellement partie du vocabulaire spécialisé des linguistes.

Comment: @jlliagre Effectivement, je voulais tout simplement dire que les deux sont probable compris par tout le monde (bien que le dernier soit spécialisé).

Comment: Autant alors éditer la réponse pour que ce soit clair plutôt que laisser "il se peut que les deux soient interchangeables".